# Eclipse: Terminate current process before re-running

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm developing a small server application that uses an embedded [jetty web server](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). The service binds to a TCP port and runs in the background. Since the application does not finish (it's a service) I have to terminate the process manually before I can re-run it (for example because the TCP port is in use by the current process).

Is it possible in Eclipse to terminate the current process automatically just before I relaunch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty also has a ShutdownHandler that you can wire into your handler chain that will accept a connection from localhost with a secret key that can trigger a normal shutdown.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.java

Alternately, you can wire up your own component with a reference to the Server object that just listens on another port for a stop key to be passed to it.

On the commandline, 'jps' is the most useful way to get a list of java processes.

Comment: I wired up my jetty component with a new web service module. Now i got a service control interface that can stop and restart the server. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

#### Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)

[Eclipse Oxygen](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/) added the [terminate and relaunch](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#terminate-relaunch-history) feature.

There are 2 possible approaches:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on the **Run** button.
2. Go to **Window** > **Preferences** > **Run/Debug** > **Launching** > check ***Terminate and Relaunch while launching (Press 'Shift' to toggle during launch from menu or toolbar)*** > **Apply and Close** > run the application

   [image: Run/Debug > Launching > Terminate and Relaunch]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the code way, rather than using any eclipse config, which I fell better. When launching the application just check for the processes running in your system and search for the process that you want to launch. If you find that application running, send a kill signal to that and then continue with your launch. Hope that helps. And it works at all times, if you aren't using eclipse also. :P

Comment: "Just check for the processes running in your system" - that's not so trivial. To find a process by name, you need to give it a name first (not easy). To find a process by port/socket usage, you need to find out who is using the port (not easy if platform independent). It's possible to write PID files or something similar, but this requires write access to a certain file with a fixed name...

Comment: @steffen, yes very true. And pid option is what we follow in our workplace. What is the problem in having write access to certain file, as long as the file resides in your application's log directory or something like that? Atleast that will give you a smoother way to solve your issue and mainly eclipse independent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet I wrote a year or two ago, and which has been doing it's job well ever since. Just add a package declaration. Call this from wherever you want to kill a process owning a port, such as your main().

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class KillPortHolderSimple {

    public static void killHolderOfPort(int port) {
        final String how = "-KILL";
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "lsof -i :" + port + " -t | xargs kill " + how});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should add that this, of course, using exec and sh, depends on the OS environment.

Comment: Well, especially `lsof`. I'd know how to run `exec` and `kill` in Windows, but `lsof` is certainly more difficult. I could parse the output of `netstat -ano`. But I can't believe that there isn't any simple solution. Everything is easy if bash is available, but currently I need this for Windows.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem... regarding the Eclipse solution, I've searched for it too, but not found it. Sometimes there is a 'Kill and Relaunch' context menu option in the list of processes in the debug view, but how to bind that to a key combination... Too bad that Eclipse seems not to have Kill-Relaunch. I would even like it to be the default behavior when debugging!

Comment: Just thought of a cross-platform solution... poll File.lastModification() of some file from inside the application, easiest from a thread. Probably a file in the target/ directory? Then either write to that file during build, to have the process die as soon as you're building. Or modify it when the new process starts. Advantage compared to killing port owner: no unexpected collateral damage. Disadvantage: requires cooperation.

Comment: Currently I'd prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13915957/1296402 since it instructs the previous thread to end itself - you can't do it any smoother. I think that's the way to go.